# What kind of Java libraries are available for generating HTML5?

Tags: java, html

Our test harness needs to generate HTML tags (for img, table, br, audio, video ..) for testing a certain module. We are looking for java libraries which can generate HTML5 compliant code.

There is a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650506/how-to-generate-html-code-programatically-in-java) which already discusses this, but not sure if they support HTML5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several available:

- [jwebutils](http://code.google.com/p/jwebutils/)
- [Summer](http://www.asual.com/summer/)
- [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)
- [itextpdf (i am not sure what html they support)](http://itextpdf.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Html5 is supported by the Summer library released by Asual.

http://www.asual.com/blog/summer/2010/10/01/introducing-summer-the-html5-library-for-java.html

They say there isn't much documentation... so implementation might not be great until it is widely accepted into the Java programming community.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [j2html](https://j2html.com/) and [webfirmframework](https://webfirmframework.github.io/developers-guide-wffweb-3/get-started.html) based on HTML5 (my favourate one). There are many if you google you will get a lot of opensource libs.

Sample code of webfirmframework :

```
Div div = new Div(null) {{
    new Img(this,
        new Src("pic_mountain.jpg"),
        new Alt("Mountain View"),
        new Style("width:304px;height:228px;"));
    new Br(this);
    new Audio(this,
        new Controls()) {{
        new Source(this,
            new Src("horse.ogg"),
            new Type("audio/ogg"));
        new Source(this,
            new Src("horse.mp3"),
            new Type("audio/mpeg"));
        new NoTag(this, " Your browser does not support the audio element. ");
    }};
}};

System.out.println(div.toHtmlString());
```

prints

```
<div>
    <img src="pic_mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;"><br/>
    <audio controls>
       <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg"></source>
       <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></source>
       Your browser does not support the audio element. 
    </audio>
</div>
```

You can also use this [tool to convert HTML5 to Java/Kotlin code](https://webfirmframework.com).

j2html sample code :

```
body(
    h1("Heading!").withClass("example"),
    img().withSrc("img/hello.png")
).render();
```

becomes

```
<body>
    <h1 class="example">Heading!</h1>
    <img src="img/hello.png">
</body>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16736506)

Comment: @jwenting I have added needful code samples