# Automatically generate HTML pages in Java

Tags: java, html

I am developing a Java desktop application. I have a need to create HTML pages through my application.  When the user clicks on <kbd>View in Browser</kbd> button a HTML page should be created with some details and shown it to the user.

Is there a way I can do this?  Is there are any resources I can use in this situation?

Any suggestions are warmly welcome.

Comment: What should the html page contain?

Comment: Some images, tables and texts.

Comment: Is there a web server to show these html pages ? Is there a FTP/SSH connexion or something like that with it ?

Comment: @user754218, see if this link helps .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323110/how-to-open-html-file-in-default-browser-from-java-swing-application

Comment: No, I just want a way to show these information to the user. I need only html files so the user can view them in their browser. I have seen some application doing this. They create html pages as reports so users can view them.

Comment: Excuse me for the naive remark, but what is the problem exactly?
Is it that you want a ready made DOM for your HTML to be able to use to generate the pages? If that is what you want, I can't help you there :) but if you just want to write a document, I don't see the issue and so should you :)

Comment: Similar question has been answered beautifully [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936003/write-html-file-using-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.*;

class ShowGeneratedHtml {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File f = new File("source.htm");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
        bw.write("<html><body><h1>Blah, Blah!</h1>");
        bw.write("<textarea cols=75 rows=10>");
        for (int ii=0; ii<20; ii++) {
            bw.write("Blah blah..");
        }
        bw.write("</textarea>");
        bw.write("</body></html>");
        bw.close();

        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(f.toURI());
    }
}
```

### Result on this PC

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use the package `javax.swing.text.html.HTML`.
E.g., it has `JEditorPane`. It provides HTML 3.2 support. You should just to set the name of the URL, and the page will be displayed, if a network connection is available. See [the example](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JEditorPane.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at - [`javax.swing.text.html.HTML.Tag`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTML.Tag.html) It provides some basic functionality. If it is not enough, you can think about using JavaServer Pages.

Answer (score 0):

The [Flying Saucer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Saucer_%28library%29) library is a pure Java library for rendering XML, XHTML, and CSS 2.1 content. Started by a member of the Java Swing team.

Answer (score 0):

Build html using any of these libraries like jsoup, wffweb, j2html, jwebutils etc.. ([referred from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879501/what-kind-of-java-libraries-are-available-for-generating-html5/45144714#45144714)) and write it to a temporary file then call `Desktop.getDesktop().browse(file.toURI());`

May be something like this if we use wffweb

```
Html html = new Html(null) {{
    new Head(this);
    new Body(this) {{
        new NoTag(this, "Hello World");
    }};
}};

File tempFile = File.createTempFile("temporary_html", "html", new File("/home/username/tmpdir"));
html.toOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tempFile));
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(tempFile.toURI());
```