# Better way to "embedd" HTML in Java?

Tags: java, html

I might have to make some Java classes that dynamically create strings with HTML tags.    I remember years ago there was a third party library that wrapped such things nicely, ie  html.tableopen() instead of writing an HTMl table tag.    Is there such a library that is part of standard Java distributions, now?   If not is there a free (as in open source )library or a better to make HTML strings in Java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically generate HTML pages in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327270/automatically-generate-html-pages-in-java)

Comment: I think people mostly use JSP for an easy way to output HTML from Java. I don't know of any full HTML model for Java, and I don't think it makes sense to create one (you would end up writing more code that would be harder to maintain).

Comment: Yes, trying to do this in Java code is just begging for pain. Do you have anything against using templates? I would recommend Freemarker (fast) or Velocity (popular).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest one I know is

http://rendersnake.org/examples.html